# Algebra in matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\ 
-2 & 5
\end{pmatrix} and\ (\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{I})^{-1}=\frac{1}{20}\begin{pmatrix}
6 & -1\\ 
2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\\\mathbf{X}\text{ is such that }\mathbf{AX}+\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix}
14\\4
\end{pmatrix}$$
How can I find $\mathbf{X}$ using $(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{I})^{-1}$ ?

Comment: $\mathbf{AX}+\mathbf{X} = (\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{I}) \mathbf{X}$, so...

Comment: @AndreasCaranti But I don't know how to divide matrices

Comment: You don't really divide them -- you multiply by their inverses.  Remember $MM^{-1}=M^{-1}M=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: As @Bye_World is saying, multiply *on the left* by $(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{I})^{-1}$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thanks. I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{AX}+\mathbf{X}&=\begin{pmatrix}
14\\4
\end{pmatrix}\\
(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{1})(\mathbf{X})&=\begin{pmatrix}
14\\4
\end{pmatrix}\\
(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{1})^{-1}(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{1})(\mathbf{X})&=(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{1})^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
14\\4
\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf{X}&=\frac{1}{20}\begin{pmatrix}
6 & -1\\ 
2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
14\\4
\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf{X}&=\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks to Andreas Caranti and Bye_World